# Pandas replace all but first in consecutive group

Tags: python, pandas

The problem description is simple, but I cannot figure how to make this work in Pandas. Basically, I'm trying to replace consecutive values (except the first) with some replacement value. For example:

```
data = {
    "A": [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)


    A
0   0
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   0
5   0
6   0
7   0
8   2
9   2
10  2
11  2
12  3
```

If I run this through some function `foo(df, 2, 0)` I would get the following:

```
    A
0   0
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   0
5   0
6   0
7   0
8   2
9   0
10  0
11  0
12  3
```

Which replaces all values of `2` with `0`, except for the first one. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find all the rows where `A = 2` and `A` is also equal to the previous `A` value and set them to 0:

```py
data = {
    "A": [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df[(df.A == 2) & (df.A == df.A.shift(1))] = 0
```

Output:

```
    A
0   0
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   0
5   0
6   0
7   0
8   2
9   0
10  0
11  0
12  3
```

If you have more than one column in the dataframe, use `df.loc` to just set the `A` values:

```py
df.loc[(df.A == 2) & (df.A == df.A.shift(1)), 'A'] = 0
```

Comment: To be more general, `df.A >= 2` will catch all groups whose number is >= 2

Comment: @smci Yes, if there was a string of `3` values as well, that would replace them too. OP only appears to want to replace the `2` values, although admittedly there isn't sufficient data in the question to be certain of that.

Comment: Nick: yes, I was trying to make the example more general. The test case only stresses the 2 case, so solutions mightn't be vey general.

Answer (score 1):

Try, if 'A' is duplicated further down the datafame, an is monotonic increasing:

```
def foo(df, val=2, repl=0):
  return df.mask((df.groupby('A').transform('cumcount') > 0) & (df['A'] == val), repl)

foo(df, 2, 0)
```

Output:

```
    A
0   0
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   0
5   0
6   0
7   0
8   2
9   0
10  0
11  0
12  3
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but I came up with this solution, hope to be helpful:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
    "A": [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
def replecate(df, number, replacement):
    i = 1 
    for column in df.columns:
        for index,value in enumerate(df[column]):
            if i == 1 and value == number :
                i = 0
            elif value == number and i != 1:
                df[column][index] = replacement
        i = 1
    return df 

replecate(df, 2 , 0)
```

**Output**

```
    A
0   0
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   0
5   0
6   0
7   0
8   2
9   0
10  0
11  0
12  3
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed a solution to this problem by shifting the row down by one and checking to see if the values align. Also included a function which can take multiple values to check for (not just 2).

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
    "A": [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
def replace_recurring(df,key,offset=1,values=[2]): 
    df['offset'] = df[key].shift(offset) 
    df.loc[(df[key]==df['offset']) & (df[key].isin(values)),key] = 0 
    df = df.drop(['offset'],axis=1) 
    return df 
df = replace_recurring(df,'A',offset=1,values=[2])
```

Giving the output:

```
    A
0   0
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   0
5   0
6   0
7   0
8   2
9   0
10  0
11  0
12  3
```